# Eigen-problem of block symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A = A_{1}+i A_{2}$ is Hermitian. Then, the block matrix
$B = \begin{pmatrix}A_1 & -A_2\\ A_2 & A_1 \end{pmatrix}$ is symmetric.

What are the relations between the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors of $A$ and $B$?

I intend to take the determinant but seems that it fails to work with block matrices. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: for that $B$  is impossible to be symmetric, nor even antisymmetric... unless $A_1=0$... you are exposing yourself to downvoting

Comment: @janmarqz seem that using the fact that $A$ is Hermitian, $B$ can be proved to be symmetric.

Comment: maybe you would like to abound